# How to use protobuf-net with immutable value types?

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Suppose I have an immutable value type like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public struct MyValueType : ISerializable
{
private readonly int _x;
private readonly int _z;

public MyValueType(int x, int z)
    : this()
{
    _x = x;
    _z = z;
}

// this constructor is used for deserialization
public MyValueType(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext text)
    : this()
{
    _x = info.GetInt32("X");
    _z = info.GetInt32("Z");
}

[DataMember(Order = 1)]
public int X
{
    get { return _x; }
}

[DataMember(Order = 2)]
public int Z
{
    get { return _z; }
}

public static bool operator ==(MyValueType a, MyValueType b)
{
    return a.Equals(b);
}

public static bool operator !=(MyValueType a, MyValueType b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}

public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (!(other is MyValueType))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return Equals((MyValueType)other);
}

public bool Equals(MyValueType other)
{
    return X == other.X && Z == other.Z;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (X * 397) ^ Z;
    }
}

// this method is called during serialization
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("X", X);
    info.AddValue("Z", Z);
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", X, Z);
}
}
```

It works with BinaryFormatter or DataContractSerializer but when I try to use it with protobuf-net (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) serializer I get this error:

> Cannot apply changes to property
>   ConsoleApplication.Program+MyValueType.X

If I apply setters to the properties marked with DataMember attribute it will work but then it breaks immutability of this value type and that's not desirable to us.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get it work? I've noticed that there's an overload of the ProtoBu.Serializer.Serialize method which takes in a SerializationInfo and a StreamingContext but I've not use them outside of the context of implementing ISerializable interface, so any code examples on how to use them in this context will be much appreciated!

Thanks,

EDIT: so I dug up some old MSDN article and got a better understanding of where and how SerializationInfo and StreamingContext is used, but when I tried to do this:

```
var serializationInfo = new SerializationInfo(
    typeof(MyValueType), new FormatterConverter());
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(serializationInfo, valueType);
```

it turns out that the `Serialize<T>` method only allows reference types, is there a particular reason for that? It seems a little strange given that I'm able to serialize value types exposed through a reference type.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - hectic weekend

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which version of protobuf-net are you using? If you are the latest v2 build, it should cope with this automatically. In case I haven't deployed this code yet, I'll update the download areas in a moment, but essentially if your type is unadorned (no attributes), it will detect the common "tuple" patten you are using, and decide (from the constructor) that `x` (constructor parameter)/`X` (property) is field 1, and `z`/`Z` is field 2.

Another approach is to mark the fields:

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
private readonly int _x;

[ProtoMember(2)]
private readonly int _z;
```

(or alternatively `[DataMember(Order=n)]` on the fields)

which should work, depending on the trust level. What I *haven't* done yet is generalise the constructor code to attributed scenarios. That isn't hard, but I wanted to push the basic case first, then evolve it.

I've added the following two samples/tests [with full code here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Examples/Issues/SO7120856.cs):

```
    [Test]
    public void RoundTripImmutableTypeAsTuple()
    {
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var val = new MyValueTypeAsTuple(123, 456);
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, val);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var clone = Serializer.Deserialize<MyValueTypeAsTuple>(ms);
            Assert.AreEqual(123, clone.X);
            Assert.AreEqual(456, clone.Z);
        }
    }
    [Test]
    public void RoundTripImmutableTypeViaFields()
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var val = new MyValueTypeViaFields(123, 456);
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, val);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var clone = Serializer.Deserialize<MyValueTypeViaFields>(ms);
            Assert.AreEqual(123, clone.X);
            Assert.AreEqual(456, clone.Z);
        }
    }
```

Also:

> it turns out that the Serialize method only allows reference types

yes, that was a design limitation of v1 that related to the boxing model etc; this no longer applies with v2.

Also, note that protobuf-net doesn't *itself* consume `ISerializable` (although it can be used to *implement* `ISerializable`).

Comment: Hi Marc, just downloaded the new binaries you posted and it worked, I've also checked serializing/deserializing using an instance of RuntimeTypeModel and they work too.

Comment: But I am curious though, as to why the RuntiemTypeModel.Deserialize method needs an instance to modify when it returns the modified object anyway. In the case of immutable value types that means you end up doing something along the line of: var clone = (MyValueType)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(MyValueType)); clone = (MyValueType)runtimeTypeModel.Deserialize(memStream, clone, typeof(MyValueType)); which just doesn't feel quite right

Comment: @theburningmonk in that case you can pass `null` in; the point here is that the API is intended to support "merge" to apply values to an *existing* object. If (as is common) you want the serializer to create the object, just pass `null`.

Comment: @theburningmonk indeed, that is pretty much essential if using protobuf-net to implement `ISerializable`

Comment: the link does not work. This `MyValueTypeViaFields` class is not in the answer.
I am having the same exception `No parameterless constructor found` and using protobuf-2.4.0 with an immutable model (no parameterless constructor indeed) and this does not seem to be supported

Comment: see my answer on how to use immutable and attribute-less classes with protobuf-net

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer didn't work for me since the link is broken and I cannot see the `MyValueTypeViaFields` code.

In any case I have had the same exception `No parameterless constructor found` for my class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class FakeSimpleEvent
    : IPersistableEvent
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Guid AggregateId { get; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Value { get; }
    public FakeSimpleEvent(Guid aggregateId, string value)
    {
        AggregateId = aggregateId;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

when deserializing it with the following code:

```
public class BinarySerializationService
    : IBinarySerializationService
{
    public byte[] ToBytes(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
            var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            return bytes;
        }
    }

    public TType FromBytes<TType>(byte[] bytes)
        where TType : class
    {
        if (bytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bytes));
        var type = typeof(TType);
        var result = FromBytes(bytes, type);
        return (TType)result;
    }

    public object FromBytes(byte[] bytes, Type type)
    {
        if (bytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bytes));
        int length = bytes.Length;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, length);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var obj = Serializer.Deserialize(type, memoryStream);
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

being called like `var dataObject = (IPersistableEvent)_binarySerializationService.FromBytes(data, eventType);`

My message class `FakeSimpleEvent` has indeed parameterless constructor because I want it immutable.

I am using `protobuf-net 2.4.0` and I can confirm that it supports complex constructors and immutable message classes. Simply use the following decorator

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
```

> If true, the constructor for the type is bypassed during
>   deserialization, meaning any field initializers or other
>   initialization code is skipped.

**UPDATE 1:** (20 June 2019)
I don't like polluting my classes with attributes that belong to protobuffer because the domain model should be technology-agnostic (other than dotnet framework's types of course)

So for using protobuf-net with message classes without attributes and without parameterless constructor (i.e: immutable) you can have the following:

```
public class FakeSimpleEvent
    : IPersistableEvent
{
    public Guid AggregateId { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
    public FakeSimpleEvent(Guid aggregateId, string value)
    {
        AggregateId = aggregateId;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

and then configure protobuf with the following for this class.

```
var fakeSimpleEvent = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(FakeSimpleEvent), false);
fakeSimpleEvent.Add(1, nameof(FakeSimpleEvent.AggregateId));
fakeSimpleEvent.Add(2, nameof(FakeSimpleEvent.Value));
fakeSimpleEvent.UseConstructor = false;
```

This would be the equivalent to my previous answer but much cleaner.

PS: Don't mind the `IPersistableEvent`. It's irrelevant for the example, just a marker interface I use somewhere else

Comment: indeed, protobuf-net supports tuple-like types (although it not might have done back in 2011 when I originally answered); but I would issue a word of caution - if somebody decides that actually `FakeSimpleEvent` needs a `int EventId {get;}`, and decides that it is so important that they change the constructor to `FakeSimpleEvent(int eventId, Guid aggregateId, string value)`... guess what happens next? My advice: if you depend on that, add a comment in your code saying "don't change the parameter order or insert parameters anywhere other than on the right - needed for serialization"

Comment: that's a very important and dangerous thing I hadn't realized. Thank you @MarcGravell
Do you know if the current protobuf-net supports adding the configuration for the message in a proto file schema or similar? I am exploring how can I use protobuf for event sourcing and versioning and doing a PoC. Thanks!

Comment: you mean you *have* a .proto, but you want to map it to your own code-first types? Interesting idea, especially now we have a fully-managed parser for .proto... I'd love to hear a concrete example if you want to log it on GitHub?

Comment: Something like that. My idea was to explore the possibility of having just the shared contract/schema (the .proto file) between sender and receiver. But each component having it's own implementation. To be honest I still don't know what possibilities I could have for an event sourced system :)