# Why is ProtoContractAttribute not valid on a struct?

Tags: attributes, protobuf-net

Why can't `ProtoContract` be applied to a custom structure? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120856/how-to-use-protobuf-net-with-immutable-value-types) and the associate answer and code, structures can obviously be serialized by protobuf-net by using `DataContract` instead. Are there any disadvantages to using this workaround? `ProtoContract` says it can only be applied to classes and enums; is this an outdated restriction from v1? I'm using the most recent release (r470).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v1 it is not available on struct, which isn't unreasonable since v1 did not support structs. It should work in r470 though; if it isn't working, you probably aren't actually using r470! Here's the code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct |
    AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Interface,
    AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ProtoContractAttribute : Attribute
{ ... }
```

I'm pretty sure there are tests that use this, and I **know for a fact** that I did plenty of "day job" work *this week* serializing structs in this way with v2.

Please check you are using the right dll.

Comment: I started off using v1, but uninstalled it and switched to r470. Every reference I have to protobuf-net.dll is version 2.0.0.470. I guess I'll have to figure that part out myself. As always, thanks for your quick help.

Comment: Apparently my problem was with Visual Studio - every reference claimed to be r470, but I was stuck on v1. I unloaded and reloaded everything and it fixed it.